# Problem with Stripe Checkout (Nextjs and Django)

Tags: reactjs, django, next.js, stripe-payments, checkout

I am trying to make a payment page in nextjs using stripe. if i guendo the guide it works correctly, but i don't want to use the form to call the *`/create-checkout-session`* endpoint but i want to use an onClick function on a div to make a call with axios.

#### Frontend Code

```
'use client';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Container from "@/components/Container";
import axios from "axios";

const PagamentiPage = () => {

    const data = {
        product_id: 1,
        price: 599,
        name: "Test",
        description: "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.",
    }

    return (
        <Container>
            <div className="product">
                <img
                    src="https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"
                    alt="The cover of Stubborn Attachments"
                />
                <div className="description">
                    <h3>{data.name}</h3>
                    <h5>Price: {data.price/100} €</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form
                action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/pagamenti/create-checkout-session"
                method="POST"
            >
                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value={1}/>
                <input type="hidden" name="price" value={70000}/>
                <input type="hidden" name="name" value={"Test"}/>
                <input type="hidden" name="description" value={"Frf"}/>
                <input
                    type="hidden"
                    name="username"
                    value={"Federiko98"}
                />
                <button type={"submit"} className={"bg-red-300 p-2 rounded"}>
                    Checkout
                </button>
            </form>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default PagamentiPage;
```

#### Backend Code

```
class StripeCheckoutView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        try:
            checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                line_items=[{
                    'price_data': {
                        'currency': 'eur',
                        'unit_amount': data.get("price"),  # centesimi
                        'product_data': {
                            'name': data.get("name"),
                            'description': data.get("description"),
                        },
                    },
                    'quantity': 1,
                }],
                metadata={
                    'username': data.get("username"),
                    'product_id': data.get("product_id"),
                },
                mode='payment',
                success_url=f'{YOUR_DOMAIN}?success=true',
                cancel_url=f'{YOUR_DOMAIN}?canceled=true',
            )
            return redirect(checkout_session.url)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(
                {'error': f"Errore {e}"},
                status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            )
```

in this case it works because I am using the form to make the request to the backend.

If instead I try to create an onClick function like this.

```
const PagamentiPage = () => {

    const data = {
        product_id: 1,
        price: 599,
        name: "Test",
        description: "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.",
    }

    const handleClick = async () => {
        axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/pagamenti/create-checkout-session`, data).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }

    return (
        <Container>
            <div className="product">
                <img
                    src="https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"
                    alt="The cover of Stubborn Attachments"
                />
                <div className="description">
                    <h3>{data.name}</h3>
                    <h5>Price: {data.price / 100} €</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div onClick={handleClick}>
                Checkout
            </div>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default PagamentiPage;
```

I get the following error returned:

```
Blocked multi-origin request (cross-origin): the origin matching policy does not allow reading the remote resource from https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_a1eRHeGL4xxJiduP9byAbmJkNpWxVSDnpJhpugqmVUsKvT0vDw74my6Mib6#fidkdWxOYHwnPyd1blpxYHZxWjA0SGc3MWBNPXNtdUZAclNDTXRJd2NcbEM2bmZVSVxJNE1idWZXcl9GbTFvRG0xQjBLbE9xQmN9f0BsT2dBTFF%2FTFE1SDZnT1x9Z1IyaGx2f2xzQ29%2FQTdfNTU0a2JBXGJsRCcpJ2N3amhWYHdzYHcnP3F3cGApJ2lkfGpwcVF8dWAnPyd2bGtiaWBabHFgaCcpJ2BrZGdpYFVpZGZgbWppYWB3dic%2FcXdwYHgl.
```

But my django cors configuration allows access to all because I am using:

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

I would like to find a way to make this call via onClick function because I need to send the authentication token in the request via headers which are not supported by the form request.

Also I would like to send a custom body in the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) (DRF) for your back-end.  The `redirect(checkout_session.url)` approach works when you are using the DRF UI because that is behaving like a server-rendered Django page with server-side redirects (returning an HTTP status of 302 and telling your browser where to go).  But an actual REST API doesn't work like that, it just returns data and it's up to your Next.js code to determine what to do with that data.

I use DRF for my back-end and Nuxt.js for my front-end.  When creating Checkout Sessions I return the URL from the Checkout Session and then perform the redirect in my JavScript code like so:

back-end

```py
# apis.py
class CheckoutView(APIView):
...
try:
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(**checkout_kwargs)
    return Response(data={'url': session.url}, status=200)
except Exception as ex:
    return Response(data={'error': str(ex)}, status=400)
```

front-end

```js
const {url, error} = await this.$axios.$post('/checkout_sessions/', payload)
if (error) {
   console.error(error)
   this.processing = false
} else {
   window.location.replace(url)
}
```

This should allow you to perform the redirect without hitting the CORS errors.

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanation made me understand the error and I was able to solve it right away